# Cannot install Magento

Tags: ubuntu, magento

I'm new in magento and I get this error when trying to execute this command line when installing magento on ubuntu. I already' tried to install the extension php7.4-intl but it doesn't work.

```
sudo composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

Here is the error:

```
    Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 requires ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 2
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.10.3] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.10.3].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install the extension?

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled the command, i Installed the extension by this command:
`sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl`

Comment: Can you run `php -i` and see if it is enabled? If not can you enable that extension?

Comment: I resolved the issue in disabling the ppa launched package in the software and update options. 
I removed php7.4 then reinstalled it, and enable php7.4-intl.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2.4.4 and higher version(s) does not support the php 7.4.

Plese check this:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html